# Append text to a txt file c#

Tags: c#

So I have a txt file called : DataCourses.txt
Each 5 lines represents a info for 1 course.I already have 20 lines(4 courses) and I'm trying to add info there using StreamWriter.I Tried :

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("DataCourse.txt", true);
{
    sw.WriteLine(tabCourses[Current].Number = txtNumber.Text);
    sw.WriteLine(tabCourses[Current].Title = txtTitle.Text);
    sw.WriteLine(tabCourses[Current].Duration = Convert.ToInt16(txtDuration.Text));
    sw.WriteLine(tabCourses[Current].Weight = txtWeigthing.Text);
    sw.WriteLine(tabCourses[Current].Language = cmbLanguage.SelectedItem.ToString());
}
```

But It doesn't work..I tried putting using infront but when I try to type sw.WriteLine I get an error.What am I doing wrong ?

EDIT: The problem was that I was missing a parentheses and the semi column;

Comment: "it doesn't work" gives us no information at all, and "I get an error" is no better really. Please edit your post with more information. Additionally, I'd strongly advise *not* using assignments within method arguments, if possible. Separate out the data copying from the IO.

Comment: Btw you missed a parentheses at the end of the "using (StreamWriter..." line

Comment: What is the error you are getting?  Also second Jon Skeet's advice... this is really bad practice and is likely where your errors are coming from.

Answer (score 4):

Your using statement ends at the end of the line and it is missing a closing parenthesys

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("DataCourse.txt", true);
                                                                ^^^
```

it should be

```
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("DataCourse.txt", true))
{
   .....
}
```

Comment: Does it even compile?! I think not...

Comment: How did the code even compile the way it was?

Comment: No it doesn't compile at all, and this is the _it doesn't work part_ I suppose

Comment: It was that simple..Sorry about the dumb question...But now when i add information let's say my last line is : English 
when I add new things the number will get appended next to the English so it would look like :  English 420
Title
Duration
Weight
Language:
How do I make it so it starts on a new line:
And It actually does compile.

Comment: Sorry, but cannot reproduce your problem with a simple test code. Probably you need to check what is the content of the variables used. And as suggested above, do not assign you variable tabCourses while calling the WriteLine on the Stream.

Answer (score -1):

```
File.AppendAllText("DataCourse.txt", "Your String");
```

Comment: What value will this add as an answer?!

Comment: @JoãoPinho it will do what the asker is trying to do, however it doesn't specifically answer the last part of the question which is "what am i doing wrong?"

Comment: Although this will have a lot of overhead as the file is opened and closed for the writing of each line, instead of opening -> writing all lines -> closing.

Comment: @JoãoPinho - You can do all he wants to do with out using StreamWriter

Comment: Probably, but if we start answering people just like this, how can we judge them when they ask something saying, hey it gives me an error?

Comment: If you want to suggest a different solution, backup it with some explanatory text, don't just past code.

Comment: How Do I make it so the new information is pasted on a new line?

Comment: @user2996891 you can use StringBuilder